# Microsoft Graph API - Delete contacts - create empty mail object in outlook in deleted itmes

Tags: powershell, api, graph, outlook, contacts

if i delete an contact over:

```
DELETE /users/{id | serPrincipalName}/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/{id}
```

It's create a mail object in the delted itmes folder.

Is this a Bug or Feature? :)

[Outlook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyW4S.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, in EWS you can use the `DeleteMode` [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.deletemode?view=exchange-ews-api)

```
contact.Delete(DeleteMode.SoftDelete);
```

In graph api it's (still) not available.

As a workaround, you can delete the item from the deleted items folder after a success delete response, for example:

```
DELETE /me/mailFolders/{id}/messages/{id}
```

Where `mailFolders/{id}` is: `mailFolders/deleteditems`, see: [mailFolder resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Deleting this mail in the `deleteditems` folder via graph API does not actually work on either v1.0 or beta, since this created empty mail is not listed when trying to enumerate the items in the `deleteditems` folder.